# C++ BOOST undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, boost-filesystem

I have no clue why `boost::filesystem::copy_file` is making trouble for me.

> undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file

```
// g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lrt -lboost_wave

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{

    boost::filesystem::create_directory("aaa");
    // ok


    boost::filesystem::copy_file("f1","f2");
    // /tmp/ccNWZltB.o: In function `boost::filesystem::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
    // test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem9copy_fileERKNS0_4pathES3_[_ZN5boost10filesystem9copy_fileERKNS0_4pathES3_]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*)'
    // collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


    return 0;
}
```

I got no inspiration from the source code of boost or its [help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_file):

```
  inline
  void copy_file(const path& from, const path& to,   // See ticket #2925
                 BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM(copy_option) option, system::error_code& ec)
                                       {detail::copy_file(from, to, option, &ec);}
```

Even such a [simple example](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppBoostCopy_file.htm) does not work for me.

Platform: `Linux Ubuntu 64`

Comment: Without `-std=c++11` it compiles?

Comment: yest it does. I just found [this bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10038)

Comment: I will download and check check the new version.

Comment: This answer to the same question provides more detail, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988317/5781248

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a workaround for this problem, replace

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

with

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
```

Or, preferably, add `-DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` to your compiler flags

Comment: What to replace with this code? `boost/filesystem.hpp` is already included.

Comment: This is just begging for ODR violations. If you're going to define `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` you need to define it globally.

Comment: Definitely use the `-DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS`  it makes little sense to use the other method as the `boost_filesystem` library lacks the scoped enum implementation anyway.   Its also easy to miss an include and there may be other boost libraries that use the include.  Either way, thanks for the post - it definitely helped.

Answer (score 10):

If you run into this problem make sure to include both `-lboost_system` and `-lboost_filesystem` in your call to g++

## Example working Makefile

```
BINARY = output
FILE_OBJECTS = main.o fileLoader.o
BOOST = -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
GCC = g++ -std=c++17
FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -Wextra

build: $(FILE_OBJECTS)
    $(GCC) $(FLAGS) $(FILE_OBJECTS) -o $(BINARY) $(BOOST)

main.o: main.cpp fileLoader.o
    $(GCC) $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp

fileLoader.o: fileLoader.cpp
    $(GCC) $(FLAGS) -c fileLoader.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(BINARY)
```

## Example working code

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

void create_data_file(std::string file_path)
{
    boost::filesystem::path p(file_path);
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(p);
}
```

Comment: In case this doesn't work and people don't read the other post adding the flag `-DBOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` will work.  See J J Hakalas post.

Comment: This worked for me! I'm new to g++ under VSCode, and not yet ready to wrestle with the intricacies of makefiles. But on the basis of this post, I just added the two lines **"-lboost_system",** and **"-lboost_filesystem",** to file **tasks.json** (before the **"-o",** line), and suddenly all my (linker?) error messages have disappeared. So many thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me with copy_file() (I already used -lboost_system in front of -lboost_file_system before). The problem arised after using -std=c++11.

Answer (score 1):

I could not compile a file that included the header  `boost/filesystem.hpp` either. This is how I solved it: I commented out the line `boost/filesystem.hpp` and all the lines that were using Boost, and then compiled the file. I then uncommented all the lines in the files and compiled again, and then it worked. I was compiling with the flag `-lboost_system` both times!

Answer (score 0):

In older boost versions it is `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS`, not `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS`

see [boost::filesystem::copy_file() missing symbol in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783790/boostfilesystemcopy-file-missing-symbol-in-c11)