# undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file

Tags: boost, makefile, undefined-reference, honeypot

I am trying to install Nova and HoneyD on a CentOS 7 machine but i have found myself with a problem.

The problem is that after I use the command make i get the following errors:

```
Config.cpp:(.text+0xa2d6): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../NovaLibrary/Release//libNovaLibrary.a(NovaUtil.o): In function `Nova::RecursiveDirectoryCopy(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, bool)':
NovaUtil.cpp:(.text+0x25a4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [novad] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/share/Nova/Novad/Release'
make[1]: *** [novad-release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/share/Nova'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

How could i fix this problem?

Comment: Please add the compiler invocation to your question. Make sure that you link against -lboost_filesystem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ BOOST undefined reference to \`boost::filesystem::detail::copy\_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007134/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostfilesystemdetailcopy-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question.

The solution is to edit the file Config.cpp and substitute the line:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

For the following:

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
```

After I did that i stopped getting the error.